# Node.js Secure Random Float from Crypto Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, binary, buffer

Not for any practical purpose, of course, but I tried to generate a secure random floating point number using the Node's [crypto](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module.  Essentially, the following:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var buf = crypto.randomBytes(4);
var float = buf.readFloatBE();
```

This doesn't work, as far as the following test can tell, in an average of 0.40% of cases.  Instead of getting a float, I get `NaN`.

```
var colors = require('colors');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var buf = new Buffer(4);
var fails = 0, tries = 100000;
var failures = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
    var num = crypto.randomBytes(4).readFloatBE(0);
    try {
        buf.writeFloatBE(num, 0);
    } catch (e) {
        fails++;
        failures.push(buf.readUInt32BE(0).toString(2));
    }
}

var percent = 100 * fails / tries;
if (fails)
    percent = (percent.toFixed(2) + "%").red;
else
    percent = '0.00%'.blue.bold;
console.log('Test ' + 'complete'.green.bold + ', ' + percent + ": " + fails + " / " + tries);
fails && console.log('Failed'.red + ' values:', failures.join(', '));
```

I'm guessing this is due to the IEEE single precision floating point number specification, but I'm not familiar with exactly how the float is stored as binary.

Why does this happen, exactly, and apart from simply generating floats until I get a valid number, how can I circumvent this?

**EDIT**: when looking at the filtered binary data, it appears they all follow the same pattern: the first 8 bits are all set.  Everything else is random.

Comment: It looks like `0x7F800000` is Infinity, and `0xFF800000` is -Infinity.  `0b*11111111` followed by 23 bits, at least one if which is set results in `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is apparent from the current version of node, the [buffer library](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/f044a6f3faa057925813e7ab95a806a6edd0728d/src/node_buffer.cc#L906)'s source specifies, on line 906, that the `noAssert` also checks to see if the Number provided is not `NaN`, so simply specifying `noAssert` allows writing of `Infinity`, `NaN`, and `-Infinity` to the buffer.